# Sequelize: disable creation of foreign key constraint

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize's [official docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#one-to-many-relationships), it's said `HasMany` `BelongsTo` ... association function would automatically create a foreign key constraint, as normally done by many orms

However, in some cases, dba would forbid use of foreign key constraint(like in my company), so my question is:

How to disable creation of foreign key when using `HasMany` or so functions without breaking other codes(i.e. I still want to use `findOne({..., include: ...})` for query somehow)

A similar feature is available here in [`typeorm`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3120)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable constraints in assocation by setting constraints: false e.g.

```
Foos.hasMany(Bars, { as: 'bars', constraints: false, foreignKey: 'foo_id' });
```